# Unity won't execute script

Tags: unity-game-engine, console, execution

This is my super simple script in unity:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class script : MonoBehaviour
{
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        Debug.Log("Something");
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        
    }
}
```

---

I attached the script to main camera:

[image: main_camera_properties]

---

After I run the unity game, the console is `empty`, meaning that the script won't run.

---

This is just a new project I created to test this because in my original project unity spontaneously stopped executing scripts. I uninstalled the old version (2019) and installed a new version (2020) as well as Visual Studio (even if it wasn't necessary), but didn't make a difference.

Comment: are you sure that there is nothing in the search bar of the console and the Log messages are enabled? In general you should maybe not use `script` as name for your components ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code that you provided seems to work fine. A potential reason for why your console window is empty might be due to either having something in the search field or having the standard logs disabled.

[image]

Comment: Hi. Thanks for answering. In my stupidity I disabled that "standard logs" thing so that was the cause my logs didn't show. Can't say I feel better for spending hours fixing this issue. And again, thank you!

Comment: @Gabi No worries. These kind of issues happen to everyone at some point.

Comment: Didn't I comment exactly that before? ^^

Comment: @derHugo What specifically?

Comment: `are you sure that there is nothing in the search bar of the console and the Log messages are enabled` ;) My previous comment was more addressing OP ;)

Comment: Ah, that. I guess great minds think alike. :D